# How to save LoginID in jquery mobile which is later used in all forms ?

Tags: jquery

I am making an web app in jquery mobile in which when login is done , LoginID is saved in cookie. but i dont want to use Cookie and i want some place in jquery where i can Save that Login ID and retrieve that in all the forms.